# How to not show localhost in ss output?

Tags: netstat

When I type `ss -atur` I get lots of connections, but most are destined for `localhost` and I don't really care about those.

How can I filter the output to not show connections with destination `localhost`?

I tried `ss -atur '(dst ne localhost)'` but get `Error: an inet prefix is expected rather than "(dst".`. Without the parentheses I get `ss: bison bellows (while parsing filter): "syntax error!" Sorry.`.

The best I can do is pipe to grep, but that has no way of distinguishing `localhost` in source vs destination (without a complex regex pattern).

Answer (score 2):

A sufficient syntax is:

```
ss -atur '! dst localhost'
```

While i'd rather use (mind the spaces between parentheses and keywords):

```
ss -atur '! ( dst 127.0.0.1 or dst [::1] )'
```

Using *localhost* seems to have a strange behaviour: while it's working as expected in `ss -atru '! dst localhost'`, when not in a negation, it appears to default to IPv4 unless using `ss -6` to display IPv6 or `ss -46` to display both: I would have expected the default is to display both.

Documentation is a bit lacking, as is mentioned in [this Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499190/where-is-the-official-documentation-debian-package-iproute-doc). There are still some [examples](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ss.8#USAGE_EXAMPLES) in the man, but this page (probably using the old removed documentation) is more useful:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/files/ss.html

(which can also be found there: http://linux-ip.net/gl/ss/ss-node5.html but the one flat page format above seems more useful)